# Webhook - Invalid HTTP response: 404

Tags: github, webhooks

I am setting up the webhook for Jenkins. The URL mentioned in the webhook is http:///github-webhook/

For this I followed all the guidelines mentioned at https://blog.tentamen.eu/jenkins-and-github-integration-using-webhooks/ After adding the webhook, it shows webhook ping response as 404.

Jenkins is hosted on GCP through Bitnami launchpad. Is there any way, I can resolve this error?